# C# cast array to element type

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, casting

I have a generic argument T which is an array in one particular case. Is it possible to cast array of objects to the array of `typeof(T).GetElementType()`? For example:

```
public TResult Execute<TResult>()// MyClass[] in this particular case
{
    var myArray = new List<object>() { ... }; //actual type of those objects is MyClass
    Type entityType = typeof(TResult).GetElementType(); //MyClass
    //casting to myArray to array of entityType 
    TResult result = ...;
    return result;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your replies, but the problem is that Execute method it's an implementation of the interface and I can't change its signature or add a new one.

Comment: See edits to my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a good idea. You have no way to constrain `TResult` to an array, so with your current code, someone could call `Excute<int>` and get a runtime exception, yuck!

But, why constrain to an array to begin with? Just let the generic parameter be the type of the element itself:

```
public TResult[] Execute<TResult>()
{
    var myArray = ... 
    return myArray.Cast<TResult>().ToArray();
}
```

UPDATE: In response to your comments:

If `Execute` is an interface method you can not change, then you can do the following:

```
public static TResult Execute<TResult>()
{
    var myArray = new List<object>() { ... };
    var entityType = typeof(TResult).GetElementType();
    var outputArray = Array.CreateInstance(entityType, myArray.Count);
    Array.Copy(myArray.ToArray(), outputArray, myArray.Count); //note, this will only work with reference conversions. If user defined cast operators are involved, this method will fail.
    return (TResult)(object)outputArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension methods `myArray.Cast<MyClass>().ToArray()` to return an array of MyClass.

I think you mean to return `TResult[]` also:

```
public TResult[] Execute<TResult>()//MyClass[] in this particular case
{
    return myArray.Cast<MyClass>().ToArray();
}
```

You will need to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

In order to see these methods.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with with InBetween that it's a bad idea, but I don't know your context and why you need this. But you can achieve it like that:

```
public TResult Execute<TResult>()// MyClass[] in this particular case
{
    var myArray = new List<object>() { ... }; //actual type of those objects is MyClass

    Type genericArgument = typeof(TResult);
    if (!genericArgument.IsArray)
       // what do you want to return now???

    Type elementType = genericArgument.GetElementType();

    MethodInfo cast = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(elementType);
    MethodInfo toarray = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToArray").MakeGenericMethod(elementType);

    object enumerable = cast.Invoke(null, new object[]{myArray});
    object array = toarray.Invoke(null, new object[]{enumerable});

    return (TResult)array;
}
```

This uses [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection) to get the LINQ extension for the specific generic arguments. The question is: what should this method return if `TResult` is *not* an array. There seems to be a design flaw.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've already have an implementation for non-array `TResult`(it's default case) so everything should work fine

Comment: I dont really think it needs to be this involved. The OP is basically asking for reference conversions (`object` -> *realUnderlyingType*). In that scenario, you can use `Array.Copy`. Check out my answer.