# Generic Import method for EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I would like to make a generic method to import data into my application.

For example, say I have:

```
private static async Task<int> ImportAccount(string filename)
{
    var totalRecords = await GetLineCount(filename);
    var ctx = new AccountContext();
    var count = 0;
    var records = 0;
    using (var stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                var data = line.Split('\t');
                var acc = new Account(data);
                await ctx.Accounts.AddAsync(acc);
                // need this to avoid using all the memory
                // maybe there is a smarter or beter way to do it
                // with 10k it uses about 500mb memory, 
                // files have million rows+
                if (count % 10000 == 1)
                {
                    records += result = await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
                    if (result > 0)
                    {
                        ctx.Dispose();
                        ctx = new AccountContext();
                    }
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    ctx.Dispose();
    return records;
}
```

In the above example I am importing data from a tab delimited file into the Accounts db.

Then I have properties, lands, and a whole lot of other db's I need to import.

Instead of having to make a method for each db like the above, I would like to make something like:

```
internal static readonly Dictionary<string, ??> FilesToImport = new Dictionary<string, ??>
{
    { "fullpath to file", ?? would be what I need to pass to T }
    ... more files ...
};
private static async Task<int> Import<T>(string filename)
```

Where T would be the DB in question.

All my classes have 1 thing in common, they all have a constructor that takes a `string[] data`.

But I have no idea how I could make a method that I would be able to accept:

```
private static async Task<int> Import<T>(string filename)
```

And then be able to do a:

```
var item = new T(data);
await ctx.Set<T>().AddAsync(item);
```

And if I recall correctly, I would not be able to instantiate T with a parameter.

How could I make this generic Import method and is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to pass a generic function that accepts the string line or a string array of split values and returns an object with values set. Use the `ctx.AddAsync()` method which supports generics and add the entity to the correct set.

```
private static async Task<int> Import<T>(string filename, Func<string, T> transform) where T : class
{
    var totalRecords = await GetLineCount(filename);
    var ctx = new AccountContext();
    var count = 0;
    var records = 0;
    using (var stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                var data = line.Split("\t");
                var entity = transform(data);
                await ctx.AddAsync(entity);
                if (count % 10000 == 1)
                {
                    records += result = await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
                    if (result > 0)
                    {
                        ctx.Dispose();
                        ctx = new AccountContext();
                    }
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    ctx.Dispose();
    return records;
}

// Usage

Import(filename, splits => {
   / * do whatever you need to transform the data */
   return new Whatever(splits);
})
```

Since generic types cannot be constructed by passing a parameter, you will have to use a function as the second type in the dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, Func<string, object>> FilesToImport = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, object>>{
  { "fullpath to file", data => new Account(data) },
  { "fullpath to file", data => new Whatever(data) },
  { "fullpath to file", data => new Whatever2(data) },
}
```

Comment: That looks very interesting but `var entity = transform(line)`says it can't convert string to T,

Comment: oh sorry, edited. Changed signature to `Func<string, T>`

Comment: now it says `The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbContext.AddAsync<TEntity>(TEntity, CancellationToken)'` but the transform works.

Comment: If I add `where T : class` it goes away but I am not entirely sure that is right.

Comment: But how would I create a new T from the type in my dictionary? otherwise I would still need to define the type myself for each import `return new Account(data);` should be `return new T(data);` or something along those lines.

Comment: That's not possible unfortunately, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852837/is-there-a-generic-constructor-with-parameter-constraint-in-c. You have to pass a function that creates the object.

Comment: I just realised there is no way to build a generic dictionary of functions with different types. What is stopping you from writing a bunch of import statements? as far as I can see it takes the same effort as creating the dictionary in the first place. Is this a one time load or re-usable code?

Comment: Well my goal is to connect a filename to a specific class, so that I could just say make a dictionary that will import that file using that said class to insert into the  database without, what would you suggest then? I originally had a switch that checks the file name and uses the class but that looks awful and I need to update for every new table with a new class.

Comment: Oh I see what you did there, that looks interesting let me try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194609/discussion-between-avin-kavish-and-guapo).

Answer (score 1):

C# have only `new()` restriction for generic type arguments. But unfortunately it's not possible to force a type to have a constructor with parameters.

One workaround for this is to define an interface like this:

```
interface IImportedEntity<T>
// where T: YourBaseClass
{
    T Init(string[] data);
}
```

In this case all implementation classes will have to implement such method:

```
class Account : /*YourBaseClass*/ IImportedEntity<Account>
{
    public Account()
    {
        // for EF
    }

    // can be made private or protected
    public Account(string[] data)
    {
        // your code
    }


    // public Account Init(string[] data) => { /*populate current instance*/  return this;};
    // can be implemented in base class
    public Account Init(string[] data) => new Account(data);
}
```

Finally you can restrict your generic `Import` method to deal only with imported entities:

```
private static async Task<int> Import<T>(string filename) 
      where T: class, IImportedEntity<T>, new()
{
    ....
    var item = new T();
    item = item.Init(data);
    await ctx.Set<T>().AddAsync(item);
    ...
}
```

Note, if you still want to use this with a dictionary it will be needed to use reflection([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39096164/5126411)).

Comment: This looks promising but I get a `Cannot implicitly convert type 'V' to 'T'` and `The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbContext.Set<TEntity>()'` on the respective lines `item = item.Init(data);` and `await ctx.Set<T>().AddAsync(item);`